# Get item selected of a spinner when its filled up from a database cursor

Tags: android, spinner, android-spinner

In my Android App I hava a layout with to Spinners. What I want to do is given a selected item from the first spinner, fill up the second one.

The first spinner is filled up from a cursor (result of a database query) like this:

```
Spinner combo1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.combo1);
mDbH.open();
Cursor c1 = null;
c1 = mDbH.consulta4();
startManagingCursor(c1);
SimpleCursorAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c1,new String[] {"nombre"},new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
combo1.setAdapter(adapter);
```

This works fine! The problem comes inside my event listener:

```
combo1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parentView, View selectedItemView, int position, long id) {
        String est = String.valueOf(combo1.getSelectedItem());
        int idEst = (int) id;
        Log.e("est",est);
        Log.e("idEst",""+idEst);
        mDbH.open();
        Cursor c = null;
        c = mDbH.consulta5(idEst,est);
        SimpleCursorAdapter adapter2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,c,new String[] {"nombre"},new int[] {android.R.id.text1});
        adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        combo1.setAdapter(adapter2);
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {}

});
```

Because, in the LogCat the line Log.e("est",est); shows this:

```
10-25 09:48:50.390: E/est(3462): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@40625638
```

And of course, that value is not in my database and the second cursor is empty and the spinner doesn't fill up with anything!! So, this is my question, how do you get the item selected of a spinner when is filled up from a database? I also tried out:

```
String est = combo1.getSelectedItem().toString();
```

and

```
String est = parentView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
```

but the result is the same!! Am I doing something wrong? Please help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your `Spinner` was filled out using a `SimpleCursorAdapter`, `getItemAtPosition` & `getSelectedItem` will return a `Cursor` reference. Use:

```
Cursor c=(Cursor) combo1.getSelectedItem();
String est=c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("nombre");
```

Same works for `getItemAtPosition(position)`

Comment: By the way, I did not realize, but there was an error in my code, in line combo1.setAdapter(adapter2);, is not combo1 but combo2...